# Порядок отрисовки компонентов

Tags: java, swing

Есть JPanel на которой расположена кнопка и другая дочерняя панель закрашенная красным цветом. Дочерняя панель должна отрисовываться после отрисовки кнопки и закрывать её. Но по каким-то причинам кнопка всегда отрисовывается поверх дочерней панели. Я пробовал это исправить несколькими способами - они указаны в исходном коде который я привожу ниже:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        window.add(new MyPanel());
        window.pack();
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static class MyPanel extends JPanel {

        private JButton button;
        private JPanel childPanel;

        private MyPanel() {
            setLayout(null);
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));

            button = new JButton("button");
            button.setBounds(100, 100, 100, 40);

            childPanel = new JPanel();
            childPanel.setBounds(50, 50, 300, 300);
            childPanel.setBackground(Color.RED);

            /*не работает
            add(button);
            add(childPanel, 0);*/

            /*Пробуем добавить сперва childPanel, а потом button.
              Не работает.
            add(childPanel);
            add(button);*/

            /*Пробуем добавить сперва button, а потом childPanel.
              Не работает.
            add(button);
            add(childPanel);*/
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Какова цель? Кнопка на то и кнопка, чтобы быть поверх всего и нажиматься.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему удалось решить следующим образом:
в классе наследнике JPanel переопределяем метод isOptimizedDrawingEnabled так, чтобы он всегда возвращал false. Тогда можно применять setComponentZOrder или add(Component comp, int index) и они будут работать как надо.

```
import javax.swing.*;
```

import java.awt.*;

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    window.pack();
    window.setResizable(false);
    window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    window.setBounds(100, 100, 500, 500);
    window.add(new MyPanel());
    window.setVisible(true);
}

private static class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    private JButton button;
    private JPanel childPanel;


    MyPanel() {
        setLayout(null);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));

        button = new JButton("button");
        button.setBounds(10, 100, 100, 40);

        childPanel = new JPanel();
        childPanel.setBounds(50, 50, 300, 300);
        childPanel.setBackground(Color.RED);

        add(button);
        add(childPanel, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isOptimizedDrawingEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

}
```

}